# How can I display Array of NSMutableDictionary data in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I am new to iPhone Development. My app is sending URL request to retrieve data from server by using `NSURLConnection`. I'm getting data in `JSON` format and I'm storing it in `NSMutableArray` as array of dictionaries. So I have an array of dictionaries. I need to display specific data in `UITableViewCell`.

My code is Here...

```
-(IBAction)ButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
     NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URl Name here"];
     NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
     self.request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
     self.nsCon=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

     if(self.nsCon)
     {
        self.receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
     }
     else
     {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error",@"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Not Connected Other View !!",@"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
     }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // inform the user

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error",@"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection failed !!",@"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     
    self.theDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.theDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];

    self.arrofDictionary=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [self.arrofDictionary addObject:self.theDictionary];

    NSLog(@"data length - %@ ",[self.theDictionary objectForKey:@"today"]);

    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];

    self.tblList=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,80,320,370) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tblList.delegate=self;
    self.tblList.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblList];

}
```

// data display in consol

```
(
        {
        "date_time" = "2012-08-31 09:30:25";
        id = 99;
        language = en;
        name = Tt;
        score = 656;
    },
        {
        "date_time" = "2012-08-31 10:08:52";
        id = 103;
        language = en;
        name = Fg;
        score = 567;
    },
        {
        "date_time" = "2012-08-31 08:22:38";
        id = 87;
        language = en;
        name = Eree;
        score = 565;
    },
)
```

Then how can I display **name** and **score** on `UITableViewCell` ??

Comment: Don't store data in your table cells, that completely breaks MVC.

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW2

Comment: Keep MCV, store all the data in One Modal class and later user use that Modal class object to show data on the cell.Do not store on the Cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You displayed data is in array of dictionary objects(yourArray). You use following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
     cell.textLabel.text = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"score"];



    return cell;
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: How have you created table view? Which array is based on?

Comment: i create tableview when Button is tapped( -(IBAction)ButtonTapped:(id)sender first method is called ).. and self.arrofDictionary array used

Comment: self.arrofDictionary is your resulting array i mean displayed array using console. Am i right?

Comment: Is tableview displayed and how many rows it contained? The number of rows are equal to the number of objects in self.arrofDictionary array. Am i right?

Comment: yes tableview is displayed.. but only one row is display and it is also blank...,yes row is equal to [self.arrofDictionary count];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16090/discussion-between-amit-patel-and-prasad-g)

Comment: How did you implement the other mandatory data source method 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:'? When you set a breakpoint somwhere in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath', does the debugger halt there?